# Get variable from the outside of while loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables

I'm doing user profile page and this one must show current info. But when I display the page it shows errors like this:
 Undefined variable: PhoneNumber in C:\wamp\www\Assignment\userpage.php on line 97

I cant find the problem, seems all ok for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect : '.mysql_error());
}
$db = mysqli_select_db($link, 'assignment');
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not select db : '.mysql_error());
}

if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] = true) {
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE       UserID=.\$_SESSION['UserID']");
}
$UserID = $query;
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users where UserID='$UserID'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    global $Lname, $Fname, $PhoneNumber, $Gender, $DOB, $Email;
    $Lname = $row['Lname'];
    $Fname = $row['Fname'];
    $PhoneNumber = $row['PhoneNumber'];
    $Gender = $row['Gender'];
    $DOB = $row['DOB'];
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    echo 'nananananana';
}
?>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Movie Renting</title> 
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="wrapper">
<div class="order">   
<h1>Таны бүртгэлийн мэдээлэл:</h1>
<form action = "userpage.php" method = "post">
   <table frame="box" style="width:900px; height:auto">
<tr> 
<td> Овог:</td>
<td> <?php echo $Lname ?></td> </tr>

<tr> 
<td> Нэр:</td>
<td> <?php echo $Fname ?></td> </tr>

<tr> 
 <td> Хэрэглэгчийн нэр:</td>
<td> <?php echo $UserID ?></td> </tr>


<tr> 
<td> E-шуудан:</td>
<td> <?php echo $Email ?> </td> </tr>

<tr> 
<td> Утасны дугаар:</td>
<td> <?php echo $PhoneNumber ?></td> </tr>

<tr> 
<td> Хүйс:</td>
<td> <?php echo $Gender ?></td> </tr>

<tr> 
<td> Төрсөн он сар өдөр: </td>
<td> <?php echo $DOB ?></td> </tr>

<a href = "useredit.php">Өөрийн мэдээллээ засах бол энд дарна уу.</a>
</table>

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try declaring them outside of while.why are you using mysql and mysqli functions together.

Comment: which is line 97 and how does your database looks like?

Comment: to declare outside what code should i write ?
like: declare $Fname; ??

Comment: Also avoid using $UserID direct in your query. Try to validate it.

Comment: change `if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] = true) {` to `if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {`

Comment: Why you are using `while` loop? Simply get result without `while` `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)`

Comment: oh, ok. Just copied this code from internet.....

Comment: Is UserId a primary key in your database? What should happen if you are not logged in?

Comment: You should have better tried understanding it.

Comment: did you see 'nananananana' ?

Comment: ok. took down the while loop. No syntax error. But page does not display any data from database

Comment: no i dont see nanana. so this means it does not fetch ??

Comment: that's right, your query isn't returning any rows, that's why the variables are undefined

Comment: why? i thought this selected exact row 
`code` $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM users where UserID='$UserID'");

Comment: see what `$UserID` contains using `echo $UserID` .`echo the sql` and rum it to phpmyadmin to check whether qualifying records are there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single scope spans included and required files as well.

For example:

let us assume in a file, example.php, you have the following:

```
<?php

$foo = "Hello World";  // global scope

function hello() {
  echo $foo; // reference to local scope
}

hello();
?>
```

This script will not produce any output because the echo statement in the function hello() refers to a local version of the $foo variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope.

Now, if you want to gain access to the already defined or declared global scope variable, $foo, from within the function hello(), then you would need to declare the variable $foo using the ***global*** keyword from within the function, such as:

```
<?php

$foo = "Hello World";  // global scope

function hello() {
  global $foo;
  echo $foo; // reference to local scope
}

hello();
?>
```

Now invoking function hello() will produce:

```
Hello World
```

While-blocks don't have limited scope within its block, and therefore, same principle do not apply, but having the global keyword define variables inside a while-block at a time when the variables do not exist outside the while block do affect the variables.

So in your while block that you currently have:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   global $Lname, $Fname, $PhoneNumber, $Gender, $DOB, $Email;
   $Lname = $row['Lname'];
   $Fname = $row['Fname'];
   $PhoneNumber = $row['PhoneNumber'];
   $Gender = $row['Gender'];
   $DOB = $row['DOB'];
   $Email = $row['Email'];
   echo 'nananananana';
}
```

Either define the variables $Lname, $Fname, $PhoneNumber, $Gender, $DOB, $Email, in global scope outside the while-block, or place the global variables outside of the while-block scope so you can have access to them, such as:

```
global $Lname, $Fname, $PhoneNumber, $Gender, $DOB, $Email;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $Lname = $row['Lname'];
  $Fname = $row['Fname'];
  $PhoneNumber = $row['PhoneNumber'];
  $Gender = $row['Gender'];
  $DOB = $row['DOB'];
  $Email = $row['Email'];
  echo 'nananananana';
}
```

or, I would do something like this:

```
$Lname = '', $Fname = '', $PhoneNumber = '', $Gender = '', $DOB = '', $Email = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   global $Lname, $Fname, $PhoneNumber, $Gender, $DOB, $Email;
   $Lname = $row['Lname'];
   $Fname = $row['Fname'];
   $PhoneNumber = $row['PhoneNumber'];
   $Gender = $row['Gender'];
   $DOB = $row['DOB'];
   $Email = $row['Email'];
   echo 'nananananana';
}
```

or even if you will not be calling other files within a file, the use of the ***global*** keyword in this case is really unnecessary, you can accomplish this in the following way:

```
$Lname = '', $Fname = '', $PhoneNumber = '', $Gender = '', $DOB = '', $Email = '';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $Lname = $row['Lname'];
   $Fname = $row['Fname'];
   $PhoneNumber = $row['PhoneNumber'];
   $Gender = $row['Gender'];
   $DOB = $row['DOB'];
   $Email = $row['Email'];
   echo 'nananananana';
}
```

To think about it from an efficiency point of view, why would you want to invoke the global keyword at every while-loop iterative cycle? I would just define/declare the variables outside the while-loop, and assignment of values will be added in the while loop as it goes through the iterative process.

Variables scope can get a little tricky, hope this helps out.

Comment: `while blocks` don't have limited scope in PHP. Only functions, class, method and closures have limited scope. i.e. you can declare a variable outside of a while loop and access it inside the while loop directly.

Answer (score 0):

you no need to use of global keyword.

just declare your variable outside of the while loop.

```
$PhoneNumber= "";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $Lname = $row['Lname'];
    $Fname = $row['Fname'];
    $PhoneNumber = $row['PhoneNumber'];
    $Gender = $row['Gender'];
    $DOB = $row['DOB'];
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    echo 'nananananana';
}
echo $PhoneNumber;
```

Now you can access $PhoneNumber from outside of while loop.

Thanks.

Comment: yes. are you getting all other variables except $PhoneNumber?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your "$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true" would return always true because it was an assignemnt, no comparision. !empty() prevents undefined indexes-notices.
2. Cast UserId to integer to prevent sql injection (even if it should be a trusted source)
3. If you want empty variables even if noone is logged in (or not found in database), you have to declare them.
4. You pass a mysqli result object (what you get from your first mysqli_query) as string parameter, it doesn't work like that
5. while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()) would return the last user, if (..) the first. If it's a primary key (userID suggests this) the result is the same.

Here is a corrected code:

```
$Lname       = '';
$Fname       = '';
$PhoneNumber = '';
$Gender      = '';
$DOB         = '';
$Email       = '';
if (!empty($_SESSION['loggedin']))
{
    $result = mysqli_query($link,
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID=" . (int)$_SESSION['UserID']
    );
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $Lname       = $row['Lname'];
        $Fname       = $row['Fname'];
        $PhoneNumber = $row['PhoneNumber'];
        $Gender      = $row['Gender'];
        $DOB         = $row['DOB'];
        $Email       = $row['Email'];
    }
}
```